# Does the inequality correct or not?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

This is not a hard question and I was trying many times,  but I could not get it. I am not sure if this question is correct or not.    Here it is,

Let $(V, ||||)$ be a normed space, and $||x||=1$, $||x-y||<\epsilon<1$. Prove that $||x-\frac{y}{||y||}||<2\epsilon.$

I was able to show $||x-\frac{y}{||y||}||<2$ but this does not help since $2\epsilon<2.$ Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\|x - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\| = \|x - y + y - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\| \leq \|x - y\| + \|y - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\|$$

$$\|y - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\| = \|y \cdot (1 - \frac{1}{\|y\|})\| = \|y\| \cdot \frac{(\|y\| - 1)}{\|y\|} = \left|(\|y\| - 1)\right|$$

$$\|y\| = \|y - x + x\| \in \left[\|x\| - \|y - x\|, \|x\| + \|y - x\|\right] \subset [1 - \epsilon, 1 + \epsilon]$$
Thus, $\left|(\|y\| - 1)\right| < \varepsilon$. Adding to it $\|x - y\| < \epsilon$ we get what we need.

Intuitively, if $y$ is close to $x$, then norm of $y$ is close to $1$, and thus dividing $y$ by it's norm doesn't change it too much.